# Show that the boundary of simply connected subset is regular

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ be simply connected. Show that the boundary of $U$ is regular.
>
> Here, we say a boundary $\partial U$ is regular if every point $z\in\partial U$ has the property:
>
> There is a function $\beta$ defined in $D\cap \overline{U}$ where $D$ is a disk about $z$ such that
>
> - continuous and subharmonic on $D\cap U$ ,
> - $\beta(z)=0$,
> - $\beta(z)<0$ in $D\cap U-\{z\}$.

### -------

I followed the hint: Assume the boundary point is $0$.
For simply connected subset we can define 
$$L(z)=\int^{z} \frac{1}{w}\, dw$$
Then take the function as the real part of $1/L(z)$
$$\tilde{\beta}(z)=\Re \left(\frac{1}{L(z)}\right)=\frac{\log (|z|)}{(\log(|z|))^2+(\arg z)^2}$$
Take the 
$$\beta(z)=\limsup_{w\to z} \tilde{\beta}(w)$$
so we have $\beta(0)=0$ and $\beta(z)<0$ for other point $z$.

Why we take the upper limit? Is this right?

Comment: Also: What does the hint actually say, and how much of what's above is your guess regarding how to use the hint? I don't see how $\Re L(z)$ can possibly have anything to do with it, because that's just $\log|z|$, which exists and is subharmonic whether the domain is simply connected or not.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, you are right. I modified the definition. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I updated some progress... Maybe it will work...

Comment: You're assuming $0$ is a boundary point and showing the existence of $\beta$ for that point? Fine. Maybe you should clarify the definition of $L$; as above it looks like $L(z)=\log(z)$, in which case $\Re L(z)=\log|z|$, not what you wrote. Oh: I bet you meant $\overline\beta=\Re(1/L)$ (???)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, my fault... Fixed. So there are two details I cannot figure out. 1. Why can we assume the point is $0$? 2. Why do we take the upper limit, instead of taking limit simply?

Comment: We can certainly assume our boundary point is $0$; just replace $U$ by a translate of $U$. We can't just use $\tilde\beta$ because it's not defined on the boundary. Using the limit would be great except we don't know the limit exists; that's like the point to $\limsup$, it always exists. All I'm missing right now is why $\beta$ is continuous on the boundary...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think the function $\tilde{\beta}$ is continuous except $0$, so taking upper limit doesn't affect its continuity.

Comment: The function $\tilde\beta$ is not even _defined_ at any point of the boundary. My current conjecture is we still haven't copied the problem correctly, it really asks just for upper semicontinuity.

Comment: Simple counterexample: $U$ is the unit disk minus the interval $[0,1)$. There's a holomorphic $\log(z)$ in $U$, and $\tilde\beta=\Re (1/\log(z))$ is harmonic and negative in $U$ and tends to $0$ at the origin,  great. But $\tilde\beta$ _cannot_ be extended to a function continuous in $D\cap\overline U$ as in your definition of "regular". Either the hint is wrong or you still haven't stated things correctly.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Actually, the "hint" is not with the problem. It appears in one of my complex analysis II class I took and I think it might be helpful. I checked some standard textbooks and maybe we should avoid the continuity on the boundary.

Comment: Aargh. Actually all this is leading up to regularity for the Dirichlet problem. For that it's enough that for every $r>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that $\beta(z)<-\delta$ whenevver $|z|>r$. We certainly have that here. See the definition of "barrier" at https://books.google.com/books?id=WHjO9K6xEm4C&pg=PA457&lpg=PA457&dq=dirichlet+problem+barriere&source=bl&ots=wdRXA4zjVC&sig=eQjfnlvt9QOeSct2GsaQKhVhYC0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0ttj-j6TZAhUf3YMKHYDDD70Q6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=dirichlet%20problem%20barriere&f=false

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yeah! You are right, Conway's book gives an equivalent definition.